# Lach- und Machtgeschichten zur Lage der Nation

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I find it quite difficult to find a good translation for:

> Lach- und Machtgeschichten zur Lage der Nation

Though I understand all the words, I still don't get the meaning of the complete sentence.

Comment: Where is this from? Quick search on the internet suggest Berlin's Distel theater has a program by that name **Skandal im Spreebezirk - Lach- und Machtgeschichten zur Lage der Nation**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @πάνταῥεῖ already said *Lach- und Machtgeschichten* refers to the Sendung mit der Maus' phrase *Lach- und Sachgeschichten*.

The more or less [official translation](https://kinder.wdr.de/tv/die-sendung-mit-der-maus/av/video-sachgeschichte-london-100.html) is

> Stories to laugh and learn.

[respectively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Sendung_mit_der_Maus)

> Laughing and Learning Stories

There is an [English-dubbed version](https://kinder.wdr.de/tv/die-sendung-mit-der-maus/av/video-die-sendung-mit-der-maus---special---mouse-tv--100.html), which airs under the title "Mouse TV", but it lacks the beginning catch phrase.

The other part *zur Lage der Nation* refers to the traditional [State of the Union Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_the_Union) which is in German

> Ansprache/Rede zur Lage der Union/Nation

So a literal translation is

> Laughing and Power Stories on the State of the Nation.

Of course most of the time there is no need for a literal translation, but one which expresses the originals meaning. So ... maybe you can think of another children TV show's catch phrase, e.g. Sesame Street, which fits. If so, use this one instead.

Answer (score 11):

This is just a little pun referring to the famous [*Sendung mit der Maus*](https://www.wdrmaus.de/).

That TV-Show always meant to tell

> Lach- und **Sach**geschichten

It's probably untranslatable without having that background, which is unlikely to be understandable in any other country than Germany.

Comment: How would you translate the second part of the sentence? `zur Lage der Nation`

Comment: @dmigo As usual: _On the state of the nation_